# TabNavigator : Go directly on a screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Is it possible to move from screen A to screen C without viewing screen B with animation in this case ?

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

    A: {
         screen: Tab1,

       },
    B: {
         screen: Tab2,

       },
    C: {
         screen: Tab3,

       },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TabNavigatorConfig](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig).

`animationEnabled: false`

You can change the tap screen without animation.